# K&R answer 1-12 (using functions to reduce the number of lines of code)

Tags: c, kernighan-and-ritchie

I have written the following program to answer Kernighan and Ritchies ch1 problem 12.

The issue is that I have never really understood how to properly use functions and would like to know why the one I wrote into this program, **getcharc()**, does not work?

What are good resources that explain correct function usage.  Where? and How?

I know the optimal solution to this problem from Richard Heathfield's site (which uses `||` or, rather than nested while statements, which I have used), however I would like to know how to make my program work properly:

```
#include <stdio.h>
int getcharc ();
// Exercise 1-12
// Copy input to output, one word per line
// words deleniated by tab, backspace, \ and space

int main()
{
    int c;

    while ((c = getchar()) != EOF) {
        while ( c == '\t') {
            getcharc(c);
        }
        while ( c == '\b') {
            getcharc(c);
        }
        while ( c == '\\') {
            getcharc(c);
        }
        while ( c == ' ') {
            getcharc(c);
        }
        putchar(c);
    }
}
int getcharc ()
{
    int c;

    c = getchar();
    printf("\n");
    return 0;
}
```

The original program (and I know it has bugs), without the function was:

```
#include <stdio.h>

// Exercise 1-12
// Copy input to output, one word per line
// words deleniated by tab, backspace, \ and space

int main()
{
    int c;

    while ((c = getchar()) != EOF) {
        while ( c == '\t') {
            c = getchar();
            printf("\n");
        }
        while ( c == '\b') {
            c = getchar();
            printf("\n");
        }
        while ( c == '\\') {
            c = getchar();
            printf("\n");
        }
        while ( c == ' ') {
            c = getchar();
            printf("\n");
        }
        putchar(c);
    }
}
```

So all I am trying to do with the function is to stop

```
c = getchar();
printf("\n");
```

being repeated every time.

Comment: Can you give us more information...  What is K&R 1-12?  What do you want the function to do?  What do you observe it doing currently?

Comment: Kernighan and Ritchie = K&R 1-12 is exercise 1-12 in that book.  It is the premier book for C programming.  In this instance all I want the function to do is replace two lines of code repeated in the program: c = getchar(); printf("\n");.  That's it, nothing else.

Comment: I know that much.  My memory isn't up to remembering every example in the book however.  I was hoping you'd describe the purpose of that exercise.

Comment: copy input to output, replace tab, backspace and multiple spaces with single space

Comment: Your code shouldn't compile at all since you said `getcharc()` does not take any arguments yet you pass `int c` into it (eg, `getcharc(c)`). It's like an DVD player with no input ports and you trying to shove a plug into it.

Comment: I have tried it both ways with getcharc() and getcharc(c).  I did compile however I am using xcode, so that is probably why it did not spit an error.

Comment: so I changed the initial declaration to: int getcharc (int c); that still does not work.  Thanks for the DVD player analogy, it has helped me "a little" on my way to understanding the use of functions.

Comment: Please note that the K&R C book describes the state of the C language _at the time the book was published_, several decades ago, and the language has evolved significantly since then.

Comment: @Elchonon Yes, I understand that. I am working through the book again as I read it 13 years ago. I am redoing the exercises as I want to be able to program in objective-c.  I think this will be a good introduction before I move on to specific objective-c resources.

Comment: Welcome to SO. Please read [about page](http://stackoverflow.com/about).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One of the possible solution is, change prototype for your function to `int getcharc (int c, int flag)`.
Now your code after some modification;

```
#include <stdio.h>
int getcharc (int c, int flag);
// Exercise 1-12
// Copy input to output, one word per line
// words deleniated by tab, backspace, \ and space

int main()
{
    int c;
    int flag = 0;  //to keep track of repeated newline chars.

    while ((c = getchar()) != '\n') {
        flag = getcharc(c, flag);   // call getcharc() for each char in the input string. Testing for newline and printing of chars be done in the getcharc() function
    }
    return 0;     
}

int getcharc (int c, int flag)
{
        if( (c == ' ' || c == '\t' || c == '\b' || c== '\\')  && flag == 0)
        {
            printf("\n");
            flag = 1;
        }
        else
        {
            if(c != ' ' && c != '\t' && c != '\b' && c!= '\\')
                {
                     putchar(c);
                     flag = 0;
                }
        }
        return flag;
}
```

---

**EDIT:**

> but I wanted to keep the nested while statements rather than using || or

Your nested while loop is executing only once for each character as `grtchar()` reads one character at one time. *No need of nested loops here!* You can check it by replacing `while` to `if` and your code will give the same output for a given string. See the output [here](http://ideone.com/DbzMTw).

> know the optimal solution to this problem from Richard Heathfield's site (which uses || or, rather than nested while statements, which I have used), however I would like to know how to make my program work properly:

You make your program work to some extent (with your bugs) by adding an `if` condition and a `break` statement as;

```
#include <stdio.h>
int getcharc (int c);

int main()
{
    int c;

    while ((c = getchar()) != '\n') {
        while ( c == '\t') {
            c = getcharc(c);
            if(c != '\t')
                break;
            }

        ....
        ....


        while ( c == ' ') {
            c = getcharc(c);
            if(c != ' ')
                break;
            }
        putchar(c);
    }
    return 0;
}
int getcharc (int c)
{
    c = getchar();
    printf("\n");
    return c;
}
```

Comment: thank you, but I wanted to keep the nested while statements rather than using || or.

Comment: Using nested loop is not a good idea always. Write program as simple as you can.

Comment: I understand that, and I can see that your answer is more elegant. However all I want is to keep the original code and stop having to repeat `c = getchar();
printf("\n");` in every iteration of the while loop.

Comment: OK. Give me some time. I am busy with some other questions.

Comment: Will do, no problems.  I will keep working through the book anyhow I'll wait for your update. Thanks again.

Answer (score 1):

What, exactly, is this `getcharc()` function supposed to do? What it *does*, is read a character from input, print a newline, and return zero. The character just read from input is discarded, because you didn't do anything with it. When it's called, the return value is ignored as well. In each of the places where it is called, you're calling it in an infinite loop, because there's no provision made for changing the loop control variable.

Perhaps you were intending something like `c = getcharc()`, but that wouldn't really help because you aren't returning `c` from the function, anyway. (Well, it would help with the "infinite loop" part, anyway.)

What's the point of this function anyway? If you just use `getchar()` correctly in its place, it looks like you'd have your solution, barring a few other bugs.

Comment: Thanks for your answer.  All I am trying to achieve with the function is to stop having to repeat these two lines 'c = getchar();
            printf("\n");' in the original code.  Which I have now attached to my original question.

Comment: Sorry, so what you are saying is don't use a function and just use getchar() repeatedly in each nested while? Is my understanding of your answer correct?

Comment: What is the purpose of the `printf("\n")`? It looks like you're printing a newline in the place of each repeated space/tab/backspace?

Comment: And no, I'm not saying not to use the function, I was just not understanding the purpose of it. If you're trying to move the loop into the function, move it entirely into the function, that's fine too.

Comment: `printf("\n")` is meant to print a new line instead of a space, tab, etc.  So if the input is a number of words on one line with spaces, tabs etc separating the words, the program would then output, the words separately on individual lines.

Answer (score 0):

```
// compiled by my brain muhahaha

#include <stdio.h>
int getcharc(); // we prototype getcharc without an argument

int main()
{
    int c; // we declare c

    // read character from stdio, if end of file quit, store read character in c
    while ((c = getchar()) != EOF) {  
        // if c is tab \t call function getcharc() until forever since c never changes
        while ( c == '\t') { 
            getcharc(c); // we call function getcharc with an argument
            // however getcharc doesn't take an argument according to the prototype
        }
        // if c is \b call function getcharc() until forever since c never changes
        while ( c == '\b') {
            getcharc(c);
        }
        // if c is \\ call function getcharc() until forever since c never changes
        while ( c == '\\') {
            getcharc(c);
        }
        // if c is ' ' call function getcharc() until forever since c never changes
        while ( c == ' ') {
            getcharc(c);
        }
        // since we never will get here but if we happened to get here by some
        // strange influence of some rare cosmic phenomena print out c
        putchar(c);
    }
}

// getcharc doesn't take an argument
int getcharc ()
{
    int c;  // we declare another c

    c = getchar(); // we read from the keyboard a character
    printf("\n"); // we print a newline
    return 0; // we return 0 which anyway will never be read by anyone
}
```

maybe you are getting confused with the old K&R

nowadays when you write a function argument you specify it like

```
int getcharch(int c)
{
  ...
}
```

Comment: Thanks.  I am using K&R the second edition, I know it is dated ;-) on page 24 he says to write the function argument as: `int power(int m, int n);` I just thought I could write the function argument without any inputs - noob me.

Comment: nothing wrong about learning new stuff, we all have been there

Comment: it is funny that we can only mark as one answer correct, as your comments are what helped me immensely.  Thanks again.